# Oracle SQL variable/parameter usage in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query below and I need to change WHERE conditions depending on QUARTER.

Meaning that I have to copy that query and change the DATE conditions to 06.2020 then use UNION.

I have no idea how can I optimize this query only with SQL because I am not able to DEFINE some variables/parameters in SQL (not using PL/SQL).

```
SELECT sum(a.limit_amount) as LIMIT,  
       sum(b.balance_amount) as OUTSTANDING,
        'LOAN' as TYPE,
        'Q1 2020' as QUARTER
FROM   accounts a 
        left join account_balances b 
              ON a.account_key = b.account_key
                 AND b.balance_type_key = 16
                 AND b.balance_date = last_day(to_date('03.2020', 'MM.YYYY'))
WHERE a.account_close_date > last_day(to_date('03.2020', 'MM.YYYY')) and a.account_open_date <= last_day(to_date('03.2020', 'MM.YYYY'))
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you running the query in SQL*Plus, SQL*Developer or similar?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

If SQL*Developer, or SQLPlus, you can use the 'substitution variables'.

```
SELECT sum(a.limit_amount) as LIMIT,  
       sum(b.balance_amount) as OUTSTANDING,
        'LOAN' as TYPE,
        'Q1 2020' as QUARTER -- << probably want TO_CHAR('&&1', 'Q YYYY') or similar here
FROM   accounts a 
        left join account_balances b 
              ON a.account_key = b.account_key
                 AND b.balance_type_key = 16
                 AND b.balance_date = last_day(to_date('&&1', 'MM.YYYY'))
WHERE a.account_close_date > last_day(to_date('&&1', 'MM.YYYY')) and a.account_open_date <= last_day(to_date('&&1', 'MM.YYYY'))
```

When you run this it will prompt you for the value.

If you used just '&1' it would prompt you for each occurence.
'&&1' reuses the value of the first occurence.

You could specify different variables using &1, &2, ...

Also you may used named variable as follows:

To prompt for the date :

```
ACCEPT dt CHAR PROMPT 'ENter the date (MM.YYYY): '
```

Or setting the value at declaration:

```
DEFINE dt='03.2020'
```

Then:

```
SELECT sum(a.limit_amount) as LIMIT,  
       sum(b.balance_amount) as OUTSTANDING,
        'LOAN' as TYPE,
        'Q1 2020' as QUARTER -- << probably want TO_CHAR('&&dt', 'Q YYYY') or similar here
FROM   accounts a 
        left join account_balances b 
              ON a.account_key = b.account_key
                 AND b.balance_type_key = 16
                 AND b.balance_date = last_day(to_date('&&dt', 'MM.YYYY'))
WHERE a.account_close_date > last_day(to_date('&&dt', 'MM.YYYY')) and a.account_open_date <= last_day(to_date('&&dt', 'MM.YYYY'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the goal of my question was to run just 1 query where the output will be total of limit and outstanding of Q1 2020, Q2 2020, Q3 2020 each record on new row.
I wanted to have it in 1 query so I do not have to copy the query for Q1, Q2, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all a disclaimer:

As I know nothing about your original query's logic - the query I propose only shows the main logic - and probably will not run as is.

Having said that - the approach would be:

Based on parameters  `:start_y` (start year) and `:end_y` (end year)
generate a list with all the quarters for those years `years_and_quarters`.

Join the `years_and_quarters` with the required table based on quarter start and end dates - and then calculate the sums grouping by year and quarter.

```
with quarters as 
(
select 'Q1' quarter, '03'  q_end_date, '01'  q_start_date from dual 
union 
select 'Q2' quarter, '06'  q_end_date,'04'  q_start_date from dual
union 
select 'Q3' quarter, '09'  q_end_date,'07'  q_start_date from dual
union 
select 'Q4' quarter, '12'  q_end_date,'10'  q_start_date from dual
),
years as
(select :start_y + (level-1) as mydate
    from dual
    connect by level <= (:end_y - :start_y) +1
    ),
 years_and_quarters as (   
    select * from years,quarters
   order by mydate 
   ),
accounts as (
    SELECT a.limit_amount ,  
           b.balance_amount,
            'LOAN' as TYPE, b.balance_date,a.account_open_date,a.account_close_date
    FROM   accounts a 
            left join account_balances b 
                  ON a.account_key = b.account_key
                     AND b.balance_type_key = 16
   )        
select sum(accounts.limit_amount) as LIMIT,  
       sum(accounts.balance_amount) as OUTSTANDING,
       years_and_quarters.quarter,
       accounts.TYPE 
from 
years_and_quarters,accounts 
where
trunc(balance_date) = last_day(to_date(q_end_date||'.'||mydate, 'MM.YYYY'))
and trunc(account_close_date) > last_day(to_date(q_end_date||'.'||mydate, 'MM.YYYY')) and trunc(account_open_date) <= last_day(to_date(q_end_date||'.'||mydate, 'MM.YYYY')) 
group by years_and_quarters.mydate,years_and_quarters.quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just aggregate by the quarter?

```
SELECT sum(a.limit_amount) as LIMIT,  
       sum(b.balance_amount) as OUTSTANDING,
       'LOAN' as TYPE,
       to_char(balance_date, '"Q"Q YYYY') as quarter
FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN
     account_balances b 
     ON a.account_key = b.account_key AND
        b.balance_type_key = 16 AND
        b.balance_date = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(balance_date, 'Q') + INTERVAL '2' MONTH)
WHERE a.account_close_date > LAST_DAY(TRUNC(balance_date, 'Q') + INTERVAL '2' MONTH) AND
      a.account_open_date <= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(balance_date, 'Q') + INTERVAL '2' MONTH)
GROUP BY TRUNC(balance_date, 'Q') ;
```

Your query seems focused on the last day of the quarter.  This arrives at that by adding two months to the start and using `LAST_DAY()`.